# When Will Traditional Chinese be Available for Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor is really great for people who want to keep their privacy.

It also has several language options.

I would like to be able to use Tor in traditional Chinese.

I am wondering when will traditional Chinese be available for Tor.

It is also known as Chinese (Taiwan).

This will greatly benefit the people in Taiwan, Hong Kong, Malaysia, some people in China, as well as many others that use traditional Chinese.

The simplified Chinese is now available on Tor, but many people who use traditional Chinese do not understand simplified Chinese.

It is very easy to convert simplified Chinese to traditional Chinese as this can be done with Google Translate accurately word for word.

The webpage https://www.transifex.com/otf/torproject/ shows that the Chinese (Taiwan) translation is 100% completed and has 0 strings to translate.

So I hope that it will be available in Tor in the next update.

Comment: Your question is good and it's shame that nobody answered it yet and even I don't know how to answer it, but fortunately I have enough reputations to place bounty on it to attract someone who can answer your question. My kind.

Comment: Is there a way to contact the developers of Tor about this question?

Comment: [#12556](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12556) is already about this, it might be how to reference it and to contact Tor Project developers.